# Hard drive failure? Can't use recovery. Diskpart & Wmic inconsistencies

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, partition-recovery, wmic

I have an Acer Aspire Switch 10 tablet (64 GB) with Windows 8.1. One day, it started to fail at boot screen (it gets stuck at the first boot screen with Acer logo).

Firstly, I tried to use a recovery. It didn't work. Windows said that drive is locked (if I used recovery with saving my data) and some random error (if I used full recovery). I tried several solutions for this problem but ended with nothing.

Secondly, I started to suspect that it might be a hard drive (it's actually eMMC) failure. I used windows console from recovery menu to check it. I opened `diskpart` and tried to list everything. The only thing I got is a `Disk 0` (58 GB). No volumes or partitions at all. After that, I opened `wmic` and listed all logical disks. It really showed all logical disks, including `C:` and `X:` (recovery), but `C:` had almost all fields empty, including size and filesystem. `Wmic` showed nothing about partitions.

After `wmic` showed me that it sees `C:`, I decided to do something with `C:`, but all actions was hopeless.

When attempting

- to open or browse files I get *"The semaphore timeout period has expired"*
- to run `chkdsk C:` I get *"Cannot open volume for direct access"*
- to run `format C:` I get *"Error reading partition table*"

So, that's what I got. I don't understand what happens.

Comment: SSD failures cannot be recovered, buy a new SSD. The down side of SSD's.

Comment: Wasn't the Switch 10 released late last year? Doubt it'd fail so fast. You can try formatting the whole drive from a live CD after trying all the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just received my tablet back from warranty repair. They changed motherboard, so I suppose that it was eMMC failure.